# Invalid workspace Error while installing new EAR on IBM WAS Server

Tags: websphere

When I try to install a new EAR on IBM WAS 6.1 server through "Install new Application" option, it throws an error after 20-30 minutes on the installation screen:

> "ADMA5006E: An error occurred configuring ABC in WebSphere Application
>   Server repository: com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.WorkSpaceException:
>   WKSP0009E Workspace is invalid "

and the logs too show

> [6/11/09 13:07:55:222 IST] 0000002b SystemErr     R
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.WorkSpaceException: WKSP0009E Workspace is
>   invalid [6/11/09 13:07:55:269 IST] 0000002b SystemErr     R   at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceLogger.createException(WorkSpaceLogger.java:85)
>   [6/11/09 13:07:55:269 IST] 0000002b SystemErr     R   at
>   com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceLogger.createException(WorkSpaceLogger.java:57)

Please let me know if anyone has an idea about this one.

Thanks

Kamal

Answer (score 1):

When searching on Google for ADMA5006E, I find the following product defect:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK52700

Maybe you can upgrade to 6.1.0.29 or at least 6.1.0.15?